# C# Directory.CreateDirectory stop working

Tags: c#, create-directory

I have a C# application, it works properly on many pc, laptop. But, I copied to my customer's pc (4TB HDD - windows 10 Home Edition), my application stop working!

I try to put `MessageBox.Show()` in some line to find where is broken. And it stop at `Directory.CreateDirectory(@"D:\\mypath")`

The PC have `D:` and I don't know why it broken.

Here is my code:

```
string now = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH_mm_ss");
string strDuongDan;

strDuongDan = @"D:\VideoLuuTru\" + DateTime.Now.Month.ToString() + "_" + DateTime.Now.Year.ToString();

if (!Directory.Exists(strDuongDan))
    Directory.CreateDirectory(strDuongDan);

string strDuongDan2 = strDuongDan + "\\" + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd"); ;

if (!Directory.Exists(strDuongDan2))
    Directory.CreateDirectory(strDuongDan2);
```

How can I trace exactly my errors, and is there anything wrong from my code? It running perfectly in many PCs but with this PC, it broken.

Is my problem related to large hard drive space?

My customer's IT staff installed my app on his laptop (Windows 10 Home) and installed the same windows to this pc. My app run on His laptop without errors

Thanks you!

**EDIT:**
My Function and my errors:

**Function:**

```
 public void makevideo()
        {
            string now = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH_mm_ss");
            string strDuongDan;

            strDuongDan = @"D:\VideoLuuTru\" + DateTime.Now.Month.ToString() + "_" + DateTime.Now.Year.ToString();

            if (!Directory.Exists(strDuongDan))
                Directory.CreateDirectory(strDuongDan);

            string strDuongDan2 = strDuongDan + "\\" + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd"); ;
            if (!Directory.Exists(strDuongDan2))
                Directory.CreateDirectory(strDuongDan2);
        }
```

**Call function**

```
 ThreadStart childref = new ThreadStart(() => makevideo());

 Thread childThread = new Thread(childref);

 try { childThread.Start(); }
 catch (Exception ex)
 {
     MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
  }
```

**Errors:**
**

```
Application: camera.exe Framework Version: v4.0.30319 Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception. 
Exception Info: System.IO.FileNotFoundException at camera.Form1.makevideo() at camera.Form1.<Form1_Load>b__6_0() at         System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext,
System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean) at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean) at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, 
System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object) at 
System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

**

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: My customer is far away from me and I don't know to get errors from application, can you tell me!

Comment: i only know getting errors from "Output" in `Visual Studio`

Comment: My guess is that it's a permissions issue. Can you tell the customer to run your exe as an administrator?

Comment: What errors from the output?

Comment: yes, i did, but got same errors, i was very confused

Comment: in my pc, my application in visual studio has no errors and working well, but in my customer pc, the `.exe` file stop working and I dont know how to get errors from `.exe` file

Comment: it worked properly in many PCs but in this pc it running fail. I've run as Administrator and full permission, the errors still occured

Comment: Try to open event viewer, if the app crashed it might write something in there. Run "eventvwr" -> go to "Windows Logs" -> "Application"

Comment: @Milana thank you so muchs Milana, I will try and update my errors soon!

Comment: @Milana yeah, my problem is exactly "File not found" but i don't know why because it has full permision and this errors does not occured in other pc

Comment: Can you edit the post and paste exactly the Error and exception you are getting

Comment: @Milana I've update !!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't usually recommend catching errors like this

However you can use a logger, or if you really must you can just push the error into a `MessageBox`. at least you will know the exception

Alternatively you could check the event log viewer, if your application crashes it will give you clues as to what happened.

Lastly, most likely this is a permission thing, but who knows. Make sure your client has given the appropriate permissions to that directory or run your application at an elevated privilege

```
try
{
    // Note you don't need to check if a directory exists before you create it
    // it does it for you
    // if (!Directory.Exists(strDuongDan))
    Directory.CreateDirectory(strDuongDan);
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
   // log here
   // or
   MessageBox.Show("Error : " + ex.Message)
}
```

[Directory.CreateDirectory Method (String)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/54a0at6s(v=vs.110).aspx)

**Exceptions**

> - IOException
>
>   - The directory specified by path is a file.
>   - The network name is not known.
> - UnauthorizedAccessException
>
>   - The caller does not have the required permission.
> - ArgumentException
>
>   - path is a zero-length string, contains only white space, or contains one or more invalid characters. You can query for invalid
>       characters by using the GetInvalidPathChars method.
>   - path is prefixed with, or contains, only a colon character (:).
> - ArgumentNullException
>
>   - path is null.
> - PathTooLongException
>
>   - The specified path, file name, or both exceed the system-defined maximum length. For example, on Windows-based platforms, paths must be
>       less than 248 characters and file names must be less than 260
>       characters.
> - DirectoryNotFoundException
>
>   - The specified path is invalid (for example, it is on an unmapped drive).
> - NotSupportedException
>
>   - path contains a colon character (:) that is not part of a drive label ("C:\").